# Macro \verb inside tabu environment

Tags: verbatim, tabu

I would like to use the `\verb` command inside of a `tabu` enviroment. Here is my example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{lll}
a & \verb+\wedge+ & b\\
c & d & e
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

I get the following compiler error:

> `! Missing $ inserted`.

Is it possible to use inline listings within a `tabu` enviroment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the starrred version of the `tabu` environment (from the [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package), the document compiles without warnings or errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu*}{lll}
a & \verb|\wedge| & b\\
c & d             & e
\end{tabu*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

See the top of [page 7 of the documentation](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf#page=7).

Answer (score 5):

The [`verbatimbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) package puts verbatim in a box so that it can be used in, for example, tables later on. [EDITED to show multiple instances of verbatim text in table.]

RE-EDITED 31-JUL-13 to show space-saving use of `myverbbox` environment.  I leave the blank optional arguments there only to show that `myverbbox` can take optional arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}[]{\wedgebox}
\wedge
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}[]{\simbox}
\sim
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{tabu}{lll}
a & \wedgebox & b\\
c & \simbox & e\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And how can I use multiple listings within a table?

Comment: can you be more explicit?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I was just asking to konze to reformulate his comment about multiple listings.