# How to use Verbatim inside tabu table?

Tags: verbatim, tabu

I changed my `longtable` to use `tabu` and now I am getting lots of errors. It turned out `tabu` does not like `Verbatim` inside the table, but according to documenations, `tabu*` is supposed to do that, but I can't get it to work.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}% 
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}       

  \begin{tabu*}{p{3\textwidth}}% star version supposed to work
    \begin{Verbatim}
    test
    \end{Verbatim}
  \end{tabu*}

\end{document}
```

Error is

```
lualatex foo3.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0.1 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5863) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)))
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.12       \end{tabu*}


?
```

According to the [document](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu?lang=en) It should work, but I might have to do something more, but I am following what it says on page 7, may be someone with more Latex skills could understand this more. In Particular, I do not understand what this means

```
It is possible to insert Verbatim material with some \csname control
sequences \endcsname inside a tabu and inside X columns.
```

Here is page 7 below.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Related question

[Macro \verb inside tabu environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108841/macro-verb-inside-tabu-environment)

Comment: I get a very different error with `lualatex`: ”Missing number“ (chokes at `p`). The error is the same with TL 2015. No error with `pdflatex` both with 2015 and 2016. Apparently, `tabu` and LuaTeX don't go along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me (texlive 2016) with `pdflatex` or with `lualatex` if I add

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
```

as first line

Comment: And it works without it if `article` is used.

Comment: @egreg yes `scrbook` doesn't work without `luatex85` compatibility layer currently, that is needed even if no other packages are used with that class.